# Set focus on input field of the form in controlled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple form on React js

```
 render: function(){    
    return (
        <div>                                   
            <form onSubmit={this.hanldeSubmit} >
                <input 
                    type='text' placeholder='What do you need to do?' required
                    onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}   
                />
                <button className='button expanded'>Add Todo</button>
            </form>
        </div>  
    );
}
```

Here is the on submit handler. I want to set focus on input field. Please tell me the more right way doing this in controlled component WITHOUT refs:

```
 hanldeSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var {value} = this.state;
    if(value){
        this.props.onAddTodo(value);
        this.setState({value: ''});
    }

    //how to set focus on input field?      
},
```

I found this code with refs:

```
 this.refs.todoText.focus()
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

---

Ok if I use refs to set focus:

```
this.refs.yourInputBox.focus();
```

Should I keep my component being 'controlled' ? What is the 'best practice'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in your input box to set default autoFocus to that input also set a ref value for the input box.

```
<input 
 type='text' ref="yourInputBox" placeholder='What do you need to do?'
 onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}
 autoFocus   
/>
```

Use this in the else condition which is needed.

```
 hanldeSubmit: function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var {value} = this.state;
   if(value){
      this.props.onAddTodo(value);
      this.setState({value: ''});
   }
   else{
      this.refs.yourInputBox.focus();
   }
 }
```

try this hope it works

Comment: thank you very much. As I understand it sets focus after render method called. But how to set focus after submitting the form with empty field?

Comment: I believe even after form submission autoFocus will remain. If you do not want to submit an empty field just type in this into your input box

Comment: '<input 
 type='text' placeholder='What do you need to do?'
 onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}
 autoFocus   required
/>'

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. But the focus will doesn't remain after submission.

Comment: I updated my question - how to set focus in handleSubmit in any way - weather valid or invalid data

Comment: Thank you very much. I also can't find another way. It seems using refs in this case - the most appropriate way.

Comment: What do you think - in this case - should I still keep my component being 'controlled'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129984/discussion-between-arslarsl-and-akshay-venugopal).